# Node Vue Typescript strange error on npm run serve, no helpful message

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, npm

I am working in Webstorm, on a Node / Vue / Vuetify project.  All was well.  I installed vueldiate and lodash.  Everything seemed fine.  But when I go npm run serve, I get this utterly incomprehensible error message:

```
 vue-cli-service serve
 INFO  Starting development server...
[24%] building (15/40 modules)
node:internal/process/promises:279
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at getMappedType (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:61620:31)
    at getMappedType (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript
.js:61637:30)
    at getMappedType (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript
.js:61637:30)
    at C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:61768:82
    at Object.map (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js
:652:29)
    at getObjectTypeInstantiation (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\l
ib\typescript.js:61768:40)
    at instantiateTypeWorker (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:61999:28)
    at instantiateTypeWithAlias (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:61979:26)
    at instantiateType (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:61962:37)
    at instantiateList (C:\Work\GitProjects\SWSWebPortal\mv.sws.webportal.app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:61595:34)
```

None of that tells me anything. I'm so frustrated working in this ecosystem...I've googled everything I can, and nothing is of any help.

EDIT:  Follow up.  The problem occurred after I installed vue-typed-mixins, vuelidate, and lodash plus dev dependencies for vueldiate and lodash.

Comment: Other than installing those two libraries, did you make any other changes? The error message hints at some kind of infinite loop

Comment: @Phil those parts were fine, I used them as tags to indicate the general ecosystem I'm in.  The problem occurred after I did npm install for vue-typed-mixins, vuelidate, and lodash as well as the dev dependencies for vuelidate and lodash. 

I'm in the process of removing them all, then I'm going to add them back in one at a time.  The really weird thing is, I'm using a previous project I made as basically a template, and I did all these things there and it was fine.  The only difference is the current project, some of the versions are a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there was some problem with a Dev dependency @types/vuelidate and the more recent versions of vue/cli or eslint or something, was not able to fully determine.  So, I just removed that dev dependency then in my validation mixin, I just had to use @ts-nocheck.

Would have been nice for a more descriptive error message, but oh well.